# Robotframework-ExcelLibrary: how to get only sheet name, don't include [u'sheetname']

Tags: robotframework

When I use keyword "Get Sheet Names" the result is "[u'sheetname']"
but I want to get only "sheetname" for next step:

```
${datasheet}    Get Sheet Names
${user}    Read Cell Data By Name    
${datasheet}    A2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `Get Sheet Names` is a list of strings (looking at its source and the sample in your output, it's not explicitly stated in its documentation). Thus to get a value out of it, you have to use the `Get From List` keyword from the [Collections](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Get%20From%20List) library:

```
${sheet0}=    Get From List   ${datasheet}    0
```

Keep in mind that a) python's lists start from 0 - e.g. index 0 is the first sheet, and b) `Get From List` will fail if there is no element at that index.

Alternatively, without using the Collections library you can just use the extended variable syntax:

```
${sheet0}=    Set Variable   ${datasheet[0]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it :)